# I need to run multiple Fitnesse Tests from the command line at the same time. How can I get around the Port resrtriction?

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, fitnesse

I need to run multiple Fitnesse Tests from the command line at the same time. How can I get around the Port resrtriction? Right now, I start the first .bat file to run one suite. When I try to start the second .bat file I get an error that the Port is in use. My .bat files consist of the following command.
java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 80 -c "MeasureTestSuite.COLighting?suite&format=text".

Answer (score 1):

You can change the port of the wiki with the -p switch, and use -DSLIM_PORT= to control the port used by the Slim server (if you use the Slim test system):

`java -DSLIM_PORT=5555 -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8080 -c MeasureTestSuite.COLighting?suite&format=text`

Setting the Slim port is only needed if the runs really start concurrently, not when there is a couple of seconds between the execution of the commands (FitNesse tries to find a free port, but does this a bit awkwardly).

P.S. The next release of FitNesse will no longer require manual configuration of the Slim port for concurrent runs, IF Slim is run in-process (i.e. DEBUG mode). So, for instance, you can have multiple concurrent test runs by a build server using the jUnit integration (which already removes the need to select a wiki port) without having to worry about ports at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port with the -p switch:

java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8080 -c MeasureTestSuite.COLighting?suite&format=text"

Comment: This only changes the port the wiki start on. If you really start the runs in parallel (starting them a couple of seconds from each other does not have the problem) you also need to ensure Slim will use different ports for each run.