# How to run multiple fitness suites at once?

Tags: testing, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Is it possible to run multiple fitness suite tests at once?

I am aware of the -Dslim.port option and setting this value to 0. Then fitness will supposedly choose an available port. However, I wasn't able to see this in action. I've always ran into this error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed).

I've read some documentation here: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SlimProtocol.PortManagement.

My use case for this would be on the UI of fitnesse and not the command line.

Comment: You want to run from Ui. Do you get this error when opening multiple tabs and starting a suite in each? First time I’ve heard this. Which OS are you on? Have you tried without explicitly setting the port?

Comment: Hello Fried. Yes the error occurs when starting the suite on different tabs and starting suites at nearly the same time. The bind issue occurs and either the test fails or completes but still gives the yellow bind error. This is running within docker using an openjdk image. When you say tried not explicitly setting the port do you mean not supplying the -p option? I've tried with -p equal 8080 and using  -Dslim.port equal to 0 or an explicit value.

Comment: I meant not setting the slim.port. I assume you tried that. I’m surprised the test sometimes completes with this error. I didn’t think that was possible

Comment: Yes that has been tried. Is this issue something you've been able to recreate? I've noticed you've been pretty involved in this project. I saw some of your responses to running multiple tests like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544706/i-need-to-run-multiple-fitnesse-tests-from-the-command-line-at-the-same-time-ho. If this is something that you can recreate, is there a way to allow for a feature request to support this? This was more of a request for the users of fitnesse at our company. Right now two users would have to be aware of when they are running tests.

Comment: In my experience running multiple test at the same time always just works. Please file an issue describing your docker setup and the exact error output on screen and console

Comment: Thanks. I opened this issue here: https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues/1326.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we resolved/found the issue. It was caused by a non-concurrent safe fixture (`fitnesse.fixtures.SetUp` of FitNesse's own test set).

The take-away: build your own test suites directly under the `FitNesseRoot` directory and not below `FitNesseRoot/FitNesse/SuiteAcceptanceTests/SuiteSlimTests`